# create json array in codeigniter

Tags: php, json

hi i want to create a json array in codeigniter of the following format . correct me if i am wrong .

```
// my json format
$data={"records":[{"name1":[{"id1":"value","subject","subname"},{"id2":"value","subject2","subname"},{"id3":"value","subject3","subname"},{"id4":"value","subject4","subname"}]},
{"name2":[{"id1":"value","subject","subname"},{"id2":"value","subject2","subname"},{"id3":"value","subject3","subname"},{"id4":"value","subject4","subname"}]};
```

i am trying to create it in php using codeigniter ..... really need your help

Comment: `json_encode($an_array_or_object)`

Comment: add your code for better answer

Comment: This is nothing to do with Code Igniter. It's just PHP. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 1):

Use `json_encode()` like this.

```
<?php
$array = array('name'=> 'value', 'name1', $some_var);
$json = json_encode($array);

// or an object
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->name = 'Hello';
$obj->name1 = 'world';
$json2 = json_encode($obj);
```